# ¿Por qué no empieza el servidor con un proyecto Symfony descargado sobre GitHub?

Tags: php, servidor, symfony3

Estoy siguiendo un [curso de *Symfony* sobre OpenClassrooms](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/le-moteur-de-templates-twig-1). Al final de cada clase podemos descargar el código del profesor, el de esta semana [está aquí en GitHub](https://github.com/winzou/mooc-symfony/tree/iteration-5). Sin embargo, tengo un problema cuando quiero iniciar el servidor con un proyecto *PHP*.

Hago esto:

```
:/var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5$ php bin/console server:start
```

Y recibo el siguiente mensaje:

> PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5/app/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5/app/autoload.php on line 11
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5/app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5/app/autoload.php on line 11

Aqui esta el **autoload.php**:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Al ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

```
/var/www$ sudo apt install composer
```

y

```
/var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5$ composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files
```

Y hacer el comando inicial:

```
:/var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5$ php bin/console server:start
```

Permite obtener una nueva error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in /var/www/mooc-symfony-iteration-5/app/AppKernel.php on line 7

Aqui esta **AppKernel.php**:

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            // Le générateur a généré la ligne suivante :
            new OC\PlatformBundle\OCPlatformBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->environment;
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Pienso que es un problema de permisos. Entonces empiezo de nuevo con [el vínculo GitHub](https://github.com/winzou/mooc-symfony/tree/iteration-5).

```
/var/www$ sudo git clone https://github.com/winzou/mooc-symfony.git
Cloning into 'mooc-symfony'...
remote: Counting objects: 811, done.
remote: Total 811 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 811
Receiving objects: 100% (811/811), 150.75 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (321/321), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ php composer.phar install
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

En efecto no hay **composer.phar**:

```
antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:/var/www/mooc-symfony$ ls
app  composer.json  LICENSE           README.md  tests
bin  composer.lock  phpunit.xml.dist  src        web
```

Entonces me fue con el sitio [getcomposer.org para descargar composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Sin embargo cuando intento descargarlo:

```
$ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
PHP Warning:  copy(composer-setup.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in Command line code on line 1
```

Entonces me fue sobre [el sitio dado por Muriano de Symfony.com sobre las permisiones](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html). Me dice hacer comandos, sobre el fichero `var` pero tengo un problema, no hay de `var` en el proyecto dado por el vínculo *GitHub*.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59204/discussion-on-question-by-marine1-porque-no-empieza-el-servidor-con-un-proyecto).

Answer (score 1):

A mi me pasaba lo mismo, eso es un error de symfony al crear proyectos.

Al parecer cuando creas tu proyecto con symfony (symfony new --full my_project) no se descargan todos los archivos y directorios necesarios, en este caso concreto te dice que no encuentra el directorio "vendor" (seguramente porque no exista).

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear el proyecto con composer de la siguiente manera:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project
```

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema en mi servidor no poder instalar composer esto en el servidor de producción.

Lo que hago es todo mi proyecto lo tengo en bitbucket y desde el servidor de producción hago el clone y luego el pull del código.

Para actualizar las librerías lo hago via FTP lo subes una vez al vendor por esta via, cuando instales algún bundle subirías solo esa librería y las que se hayan actualizado.

Es un método que la primera vez de debe tener paciencia demora unas horas pero luego se trabaja sin mayor dificultad.

Lógicamente en tu máquina de desarrollo ahí si trabajas con total normalidad como te deben indicar en el curso.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para symphony es necesario que tengas instalado composer, luego de asegurarte de ello bajas el proyecto de repositorio, ingresas y ejecutas composer install

1. Instala composer (si estas en windows usa el Composer-Setup.exe)
2. clona el proyecto
3. Ingresa al directorio del proyecto
4. Ejecuta composer install
5. Ejecuta php bin/console .....

Suerte